# Upload videos from gallery using Photos framework

Tags: ios, objective-c, photokit, photosframework

What is the best way to upload videos from gallery using Photos framework? 
Before I used ALAssetRepresentation and next method:

```c
- (NSUInteger)getBytes:(uint8_t *)buffer fromOffset:(long long)offset length:(NSUInteger)length error:(NSError **)error;
```

this allowed to upload file without first copying it to app temp directory. Don’t see any alternatives in Photos framework. Only way seems to use AVAssetExportSession -> export to local directory -> upload, but this requires additional storage space (could be a problem, if video is too big)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Seems the only valid way is to request `AVAsset` from `PHImageManager`, and check if returned asset is `AVURLAsset`. In this case URL can be used to directly access file and get needed chunk of bytes:

```c
[[PHImageManager defaultManager] requestAVAssetForVideo:videoAsset options:nil resultHandler:^(AVAsset *asset, AVAudioMix *audioMix, NSDictionary *info) {
  if ([asset isKindOfClass:[AVURLAsset class]]) {
    NSURL *URL = [(AVURLAsset *)asset URL];
    // use URL to get file content
  }
}];
```

This will not work with slow motion videos, because `AVComposition` instead of `AVURLAsset` is returned. Possible solution is to use `PHVideoRequestOptionsVersionOriginal` video file version:

```c
PHVideoRequestOptions *options = [[PHVideoRequestOptions alloc] init];
options.version = PHVideoRequestOptionsVersionOriginal;

[[PHImageManager defaultManager] requestAVAssetForVideo:videoAsset options:options resultHandler:^(AVAsset *asset, AVAudioMix *audioMix, NSDictionary *info) {
  if ([asset isKindOfClass:[AVURLAsset class]]) {
    NSURL *URL = [(AVURLAsset *)asset URL];
    // use URL to get file content
  }
}];
```

And to get fullsize image url:

```c
PHContentEditingInputRequestOptions *options = [[PHContentEditingInputRequestOptions alloc] init];
options.canHandleAdjustmentData = ^BOOL(PHAdjustmentData *adjustmentData) {
  return YES;
};

[imageAsset requestContentEditingInputWithOptions:options completionHandler:^(PHContentEditingInput *contentEditingInput, NSDictionary *info) {
  // use contentEditingInput.fullSizeImageURL
}];
```

Comment: Basil, this solution is used in our live app without any problem. please share part of code that is not working for more information

Comment: In my case, I planed to use the URL as a input stream for uploading big video. But failed, because the `hasBytesAvailable` of that stream returns NO.

Comment: Not working for sharing to facebook. Any suggestion.

Comment: Reading of url often fails when you fetch it as NSData for instance.