# Getting url for PHAsset

Tags: ios, objective-c, avplayer, avkit

I am using a custom image picker to pick a time lapse and I want to get the url of the picked time lapse so I can then play the time lapse.

```
- (void)qb_imagePickerController:(QBImagePickerController *)imagePickerController didFinishPickingAssets:(NSArray *)assets {
for (PHAsset *asset in assets) {



    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString: assetURLgoesHere];
    AVURLAsset *avAsset = [AVURLAsset URLAssetWithURL:url options:nil];
    AVPlayerItem *playerItem = [AVPlayerItem playerItemWithAsset:avAsset];
    AVPlayer *videoPlayer = [AVPlayer playerWithPlayerItem:playerItem];


    [videoPlayer play];

}

[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:NULL];
}
```

This is what I have at the moment but I need to get the url of the asset.

I usually use swift but this custom image picker is written in objective-c. so I am a bit of a objective-c noob

**Updated code**

```
- (void)qb_imagePickerController:(QBImagePickerController *)imagePickerController didFinishPickingAssets:(NSArray *)assets {
for (PHAsset *asset in assets) {

    - (PHImageRequestID)requestAVAssetForVideo:(PHAsset *)asset options:(PHVideoRequestOptions *)options resultHandler:(void (^)(AVAsset *asset, AVAudioMix *audioMix, NSDictionary *info))resultHandler

    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString: asset];
    AVURLAsset *avAsset = [AVURLAsset URLAssetWithURL:url options:nil];
    AVPlayerItem *playerItem = [AVPlayerItem playerItemWithAsset:avAsset];
    AVPlayer *videoPlayer = [AVPlayer playerWithPlayerItem:playerItem];


    [videoPlayer play];

}

[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:NULL];
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should use [`PHImageManager`](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Photos/Reference/PHImageManager_Class/index.html).

Use the class's `sharedInstance` and call this method with your `PHAsset`, options, and a completion block handler:

```
- (PHImageRequestID)requestAVAssetForVideo:(PHAsset *)asset options:(PHVideoRequestOptions *)options resultHandler:(void (^)(AVAsset *asset, AVAudioMix *audioMix, NSDictionary *info))resultHandler
```

The handler will give you an `AVAsset` you should use for your `AVPlayerItem`, as opposed to a URL.

Example:

```
[[PHImageManager defaultManager] requestAVAssetForVideo:asset options:nil resultHandler:^(AVAsset *avAsset, AVAudioMix *audioMix, NSDictionary *info) {
  // Use the AVAsset avAsset
  AVPlayerItem *playerItem = [AVPlayerItem playerItemWithAsset:avAsset];
  AVPlayer *videoPlayer = [AVPlayer playerWithPlayerItem:playerItem];
}];
```

Beware its likely asynchronous which will interfere with your application flow further.

Comment: I tried this but i am not sure where to put this code. I tried putting it after did finish picking with assets but then I get an error. I really have next to no objective-c experience

Comment: Please add your updated code to your question so I can take a look @TomFox

Comment: When I said to 'call' the method, I meant that you should use `[[PHImageManager sharedInstance] requestAVAssetForVideo...]` @TomFox , sorry for any confusion. I didn't have a complete code snippet handy with its use so I just put the method declaration from the docs in my answer

Comment: I added an example. [See this also.](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29791351/2446155)

Answer (score 9):

By the way, if you want the actual URL--that is to say, the same one that UIImagePickerController passes to an AVPlayerItem when it is created, and the same one that looks like the URL one would use with AVAssetReader/Writer--then do this:

```
[[PHImageManager defaultManager] requestAVAssetForVideo:phAsset options:nil resultHandler:^(AVAsset *avAsset, AVAudioMix *audioMix, NSDictionary *info) {
    NSURL *url = (NSURL *)[[(AVURLAsset *)avAsset URL] fileReferenceURL];
    NSLog(@"url = %@", [url absoluteString]);
    NSLog(@"url = %@", [url relativePath]);
 }];
```

Whereas phAsset is the PHAsset object, and avAsset is the resulting AVAsset object generated by PHImageManager, the output to the console from the above code will produce, for example:

```
2016-04-16 01:15:40.155 ChromaEpsilon[3423:933358] url = file:///.file/id=16777218.8262005
2016-04-16 01:15:40.155 ChromaEpsilon[3423:933358] url = /private/var/mobile/Media/DCIM/108APPLE/IMG_8421.MOV
```

Comment: Can u please give a swift 3 version for this.

Answer (score 8):

> For Swift 3.0
>   You can get string url for image and video from PHAsset object

```
asset.requestContentEditingInput(with: PHContentEditingInputRequestOptions(), completionHandler: { (contentEditingInput, dictInfo) in

    if asset.mediaType == .image
    {
      if let strURL = contentEditingInput?.fullSizeImageURL?.absoluteString
      {
         print("IMAGE URL: ", strURL)
      }
    }
    else
    {
      if let strURL = (contentEditingInput!.avAsset as? AVURLAsset)?.url.absoluteString
      {
         print("VIDEO URL: ", strURL)
      }
    }
  })
```

Answer (score 5):

**Proper answer of @HirenPanchal in Swift 4.0(also working in Swift 5.0+) and iOS 9.0+**

```
func getUrlFromPHAsset(asset: PHAsset, callBack: @escaping (_ url: URL?) -> Void)
{
    asset.requestContentEditingInput(with: PHContentEditingInputRequestOptions(), completionHandler: { (contentEditingInput, dictInfo) in

        if let strURL = (contentEditingInput!.audiovisualAsset as? AVURLAsset)?.url.absoluteString
        {
            PRINT("VIDEO URL: \(strURL)")
            callBack(URL.init(string: strURL))
        }
    })
}
```

Answer (score 2):

### Get video URL from PHAsset in Swift 4.2 from didFinishPickingAssets in QBImagePickerController

```
let imagePicker = QBImagePickerController()
imagePicker.delegate = self
imagePicker.numberOfColumnsInPortrait = 2
imagePicker.maximumNumberOfSelection = 2
imagePicker.allowsMultipleSelection = true
imagePicker.mediaType = .video
        
self.present(imagePicker, animated: true, completion: nil)

func qb_imagePickerController(_ imagePickerController: 
QBImagePickerController!, didFinishPickingAssets assets: [Any]!) {
    for asset in assets
    {
        PHCachingImageManager().requestAVAsset(forVideo: asset as! PHAsset, 
        options: nil, resultHandler: {(asset, audioMix, info) -> Void in
            if asset != nil {
                let avasset = asset as! AVURLAsset
                let urlVideo = avasset.url
                yourarray.add(urlVideo as URL)
            }
            
        })

    }

    
    imagePickerController.dismiss(animated: true) {
         //You can access video urls here
         print("Total Videos:\(yourarray.count)")
    }
    
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

In speking of video url from `PHAsset`, I had once prepared a utility function on **Swift 2** (playing videos from `PHAsset`). Sharing in this answer, might help someone.

```
static func playVideo (view:UIViewController, asset:PHAsset)
```

Please check this [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39603983/1084174)